# maven-surefire-plugin doesnot work in SpringBoot 2.2.2.RELEASE and above

Tags: maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit, parallel-testing

I have used maven-surefire-plugin in my Maven project to execute the tests in parallel.
everything work great.
When I have upgraded to SpringBoot 2.2.2.RELEASE and above, tests stop running in parallel.
This is how I use the plugin :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there a way to execute tests in parallel ? with this plug-in ?

I have uploaded a small maven project with two modules:

- a not working module with springBoot 2.2.6.RELEASE
- a working module with springBoot 1.5.9.RELEASE

  Both modules are identical except SprintBoot version

Comment: From which version of spring boot have you upgraded? And what does "tests stop running.." mean? Which test framework are you using junit/testng / JUnit Jupiter? It would help to see the full pom file...and a log output of the build..

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't upgraded to the most recent [2.2.6.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/26/spring-boot-2-2-6-available-now) ?

Comment: In 2.2.6.RELEASE it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I have upgraded from springBoot 1.5.9.RELEASE version.

Comment: from version 2.2.2.RELEASE tests stop running IN PARALLEL

Comment: Can you also answer the other questions please? Testframework?

Comment: I use  Jupiter 5.5.2 .  but I have checked the behaviour with  JUnit 4.7.1 as well.  The Junit version difference doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: Can you please show an example of your test code and also a full pom file and of course there are difference cause JUnit Jupiter is completely different from JUnit 4... or an example project on GitHub ...

Comment: A demo project can be found at : https://github.com/idaamit/parallel-plugin-investigation

Comment: Great. That helps. First thing is that Spring Boot 1.5.X uses  only JUnit 4 ...which transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter-test. Spring boot 2.2.X uses JUnit Jupiter only. After taking a look into that project I realize that cucumber seemed to be not supporting JUnit Jupiter directly. Only supports JUnit 4 (https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#junit). If you run on JUnit Vintage parallelization does not work cause it's not supported via JUnit Vintage.If I correctly understood the docs of cucumber only JUnit 4 is supported. that means if you need parallel you have to stuck with JUnit 4

Comment: Hi, I've created a pull request against your git repo which excludes the JUnit Jupiter deps from the Spring 2.2X project and added JUnit 4 which results in running as before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a configuration in pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem here is of course that you are using JUnit 4 only.